# SQL Server update using three tables join

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have an existing Oracle update statement, which I am trying to convert into a SQL Server update statement.

I already converted the SQL from Oracle functions to SQL Server functions as shown below.

But when I run this query, it is not able to understand the alias a in the SQL statement. It errors out with

> Msg 102, Level 15, state 1, line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'a' in

Code:

```
UPDATE related_opty_plan_n_dim a
SET a.days_to_create_interlock = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                  FROM date_dim b
                                  LEFT JOIN plan_n_dim p ON a.plan_key = p.plan_key
                                  WHERE b.cal_date >= CAST(p.createddate AS DATE)
                                    AND b.cal_date <= CAST(a.createddate AS DATE)
                                    AND b.weekday_flag = 'Y');
```

Comment: Check if the SET statement can receive an alias on the column being updated.  Think that removing the "a." table alias in "SET a.days_to create_interlock . . ." could solve your problem.
No guarantee - but you are only updating one table, it should not need to be aliased on the left hand side of the SET construct.
Another option might be that the format of the UPDATE statement does not conform to SQL Server's syntax rules.  You might need to use the UPDATE x FROM (......) SET ... syntax.

Comment: but i am using columns in joining with 2nd and 3rd tables from the update table.

Comment: Think that removing the "a." table alias in "SET a.days_to create_interlock . . .".  Only suggesting you remove that single "a." instance.  No others.  See @lptr's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update a
set days_to_create_interlock = (SELECT COUNT(*)…)
from related_opty_plan_n_dim as a
```

Comment: let me try this. It looks promising. This is what i was playing with.

Comment: this format is what i was looking and i tried to add this table as a before the join. now i understand i add at the end. Thanks.

Comment: ..@user13771510 .. the left join in the subquery isn’t a “left” join because the right table (p) is referenced in the where clause .. WHERE b.cal_date >= CAST(p.createddate AS DATE)